# How other players can play my maps?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I created now some different maps with the editor on gta online.
Now I want to let other players play and rate my maps. But how can I achieve, that other players play my maps?

The only way I can let other players play my maps is, when I host a race with my own map and search for players. But how is it possible to play other players maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play on custom maps, other players currently have to go through the [Rockstar Social Club](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com) website.

From here they will be able to find your game and bookmark it which will cause it to show up in game so they can get back to it quickly in the future using the beacons on the map (bookmarks are gold).

Alternatively, as you've mentioned, you can host a job through the online screen (Online>Jobs>Host Job...) and then invite your friends/lobby members/whatever, just like you would in a normal lobby. This way they don't need to bookmark the job beforehand, it'll be automatically loaded for them when they join.

Comment: Hm. I think I should take a better look to the website. Thank you.